# variable routes values get in static files path

Tags: html, css, flask, visual-studio-code, web-applications

I was working on web app using cs50 ide but when i changed to my machine everything worked except for variable-routes their values get in the start of static files

I am using Flask and VS Code and it was working well on the ide and I made sure to copy everything and made sure I copied correctly

This is one of my routes but this route adds the word "posts" to the static file path

```
@app.route("/posts/<post_id>", methods=["GET", "POST"])
    
    @login_required
    
    def open_post(post_id):
    
       if request.method == "GET":
            .....
```

Comment: Most likely relates to the way you're including static files in the template.  You haven't provided a code sample of this in your question though ...

Comment: I didn't because I think it wasn't the problem as there are other files that extends from my main html file the same thing and the main reason that even the pictures in my html file didn't work either and yes my fault i forgot to mention this :D

Comment: and if how you still need to see I can add them I just thought they won't be useful

Comment: My thinking is if a template is rendered from the `/posts/<post_id>` route, and the static file is included like `static/something.js` instead of `/static/something.js` (note the missing preceding slash) then the browser would translate that to `/posts/static/something.js`.  Of course, using the `url_for` method to include static assets from your templates would ensure this is correct, thus I thought this part of the template code was relevant to the question.

Comment: Actually adding that (preceding slash) at the start worked Thank You :)